# Compiler error when passing rvalue reference through variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, rvalue-reference

There is a requirement where I need to pass an rvalue from 1 function to another function via variadic template. To avoid real code complexity, minimal example is below using `int`:

```
void Third (int&& a)
{}

template<typename... Args>
void Second (Args&&... args) {
  Third(args...);
}

void First (int&& a) {
  Second(std::move(a));  // error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
  Third(std::move(a));  // OK
}

int main () {
  First(0);
}
```

`First(0)` is called properly. If I invoke `Third(int&&)` directly then it works fine using `std::move()`. But calling `Second(Args&&...)` [results in](http://ideone.com/RLNY7W):

```
error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
   Third(args...);        ^
note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Third(int&&)’
 void Third (int&& a)
```

What is the correct way to achieve the successful compilation for `Second(Args&&...)`?

FYI: In real code the `Second(Args&&...)` is mix of lvalues, rvalues and rvalue references. Hence if I use:

```
Third(std::move(args...));
```

[it works](http://ideone.com/gClJPj). But when there are mix of arguments, it has problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve the rvalue-ness, you have to `move` or `forward` the parameter(s)

```
template<typename... intrgs>
void Second (intrgs&&... args) {
  Third(std::forward<intrgs>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: `move` would cast them unconditionally to rvalues, that doesn't "preserve" rvalue-ness.

Comment: @Barry, can you or Bo evaluate more on why `std::forward` should be preferred over `std::move`?

Comment: @iammilind - `std::move` will always make the parameter an rvalue, even if it wasn't originally. `std::forward` will preserve the way the parameters were passed (like Barry says). If you *always* pass an rvalue to `Second`, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `std::forward`:

```
template<typename... intrgs>
void Second (intrgs&&... args) {
  Third(std::forward<intrgs>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Can you evaluate more on why `std::move` wouldn't be a good idea?